# Headless browsing working on google page but not on an AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, selenium, headless-browser

I wrote the sample `selenium` script to perform `headless browser testing` on a google page.

```
public class Headless 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        HtmlUnitDriver unitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
        // WebDriver unitDriver=new FirefoxDriver();
         unitDriver.manage().window().maximize();
         System.out.println("window maximise");

        unitDriver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=k36cVsa6OubI8Aec14bICQ&gws_rd=ssl");
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        System.out.println("at google page");
        System.out.println("Title of the page is -> " + unitDriver.getTitle());

        //unitDriver.findElement(By.id("gb_70")).click();
        unitDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='gb_70']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(20000);

        System.out.println("Title of the page is -> " + unitDriver.getTitle());

    }
}
```

The output is what I have expected.

But, when I tried the same script on my `AngularJS` application (making necessary modification in URL and xpaths), It is not at all executing the script.
The output is shown as blank.

What is the reason the script is success in case of Google page but not on the `AngularJS` application?

`Note:` To make sure the script is correct, I tested the AngularJS application on FF. It is working fine.

Comment: do u have a public URL where we can replicate the same issue

Comment: @MrunalGosar I will share the sample URL.